# Swift. How to iterate through Dictionary value : var a: [String : [String]]?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I need to iterate through  Dictionary value (value = array) with a for loop. And 
sort in reverse order in each array. How I can do it?

```
var a: [String : [String]]
```

Expected Result looks like:

```
["C": ["Camilla", "Cecelia", "Colette"], "B": ["Ben", "Bob"], "A": ["Alex", "Andy"]]
```

**UPD:**

I have function:

```
func someFunc(array: [String]) -> [String : [String]] {
    let groupedDictionary  = Dictionary (grouping: array, by:  { String($0.first!) }nc).filter{ $0.value.count > 1 }
```

And i have some array:

```
var array = ["Camilla", "Andy", "Bob", "Ben", "Alex", "Colette", "Camilla"]
```

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen yes

Comment: no order with dictionary

Comment: It's impossible to maintain the order with the dictionary

Comment: You say you want to iterate the dictionary and sort the arrays but at the same time it looks like you want to sort the dictionary keys as well so which one is it?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I have a function that takes an array and returns a dictionary. function:
1. Put the names in the dictionary, where the key is the first letter and the value is an array of names.
2. Filter by count of values
3. Sort in reverse alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created dictionary from your array by grouping you can use a for loop to filter on size and sort

```
func someFunc(array: [String]) -> [String : [String]] {
    let groupedDictionary  = Dictionary (grouping: array, by:  { String($0.first!) })
    var result: [String: [String]] = [:]

    for (key, value) in groupedDictionary {
        if value.count > 1 {
            result[key] = value.sorted(by: >)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: not working,  a randomly sorted dictionary returns

Comment: @freddyK This has already been explained in comments to your question, dictionaries can't be sorted! Update your question and explain what you want but restrict your question to something that is actually possible

Comment: is it possible to sort an array that is a dictionary value?

Comment: That is what I am doing in the code above

Comment: sort in reverse alphabetical order like ["C": ["Camilla", "Cecelia", "Colette"], "B": ["Ben", "Bob"], "A": ["Alex", "Andy"]]

Comment: @freddyK Again, you can't sort a dictionary. (and the arrays are not sorted in reversed order in your example)

Answer (score 0):

There is no order with dictionary but you can sort the keys

```
var arr = Array(dic.keys) 
arr.sort(by:>)
```

Then access dictionary with `arr`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
let dictInitial = [ "A": ["Alex", "Andy"], "C": ["Camilla", "Cecelia", "Colette"], "B": ["Ben", "Bob"]]

let keys = Array(dictInitial.keys).sorted(by: >)


// get values

for key in keys {
    print("KEY:", key, "VALUES :", dictInitial[key]!)
}
```

**Output:**

```
KEY: C VALUES : ["Camilla", "Cecelia", "Colette"]
KEY: B VALUES : ["Ben", "Bob"]
KEY: A VALUES : ["Alex", "Andy"]
```

Answer (score 0):

@freddyK First of all there is a logical mistake in your `someFunc` code. you have to enhance that first as it will create a group only if the two objects having the same alphabet. It should be like `{ $0.value.count > 0 }`.

Below snippet can help you.

```
let objDict = someFunc(array: ["Zoro", "Camilla", "Andy", "Bob", "Ben", "Alex", "Colette", "Camilla"])

let sortedDic = objDict.sorted { (aDic, bDic) -> Bool in
    return aDic.key > bDic.key
}
print(sortedDic)
```

Answer (score 0):

@freddyk your update question is partial right. you just need to sort your dictionary by it's key with descending order. but you need to change the dictionary format from `[string:[string]]`to`[(key: String, value: [String])]`
Both is same but swift is highly coupled with datatype that's why we cannot convert this

```
 var a: [String] = ["Ben", "Bob","Camilla","Andy","Cecelia", "Colette","Alex"]
func someFunc(array: [String]) -> [(key: String, value: [String])] {
    let groupDict = Dictionary (grouping: array, by:  { String($0.first!) }).sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
        return str1.key.compare(str2.key) == .orderedDescending
    }
    return groupDict

}
let groupedDictionary = someFunc(array: a)
print(groupedDictionary)
```

So it's output will be like below

**Output : [(key: "C", value: ["Camilla", "Cecelia", "Colette"]), (key: "B", value: ["Ben", "Bob"]), (key: "A", value: ["Andy", "Alex"])]**

Comment: homework: it should  be only like this [String]) -> [String : [String]]